# How can I add the claimed coupon as a url parameter?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm going to be using the ClaimRow() to pull a new or existing coupon code. I am wondering if there's a way I can have that code populate not only in the body of the email but also as a URL parameter.

Is that possible?

best,

Ted

Answer (score 2):

Yes you should be able to use the same variable you set from the ClaimRow() function for your CouponCode (lets assume @CouponCode) in your url.

Below are a couple example ways to handle it:

Inline fill:

```
<a href="https://www.google.com?coupon=%%=v(@CouponCode)=%%">
```

If Cloudpage:

```
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(Cloudpagesurl(@myID,"coupon",@CouponCode))=%%">
```

Concat And Redirect:

```
<a href="%%=RedirectTo(Concat("https://www.google.com?coupon=",@CouponCode))=%%">
```

I am sure there are other options, but these are the major ones I see used.

Comment: Thank you for your help here. Would I be able to add this to the Additional Attributes within the content builder template? And would I just input %%=v(@CouponCode)=%% ?

Comment: @Ted I have not tried it to validate 100%, but I believe it should work. Yes just put `%%=v(@CouponCode)=%%`.